# Create b2c user with authenitcation method as email for SSPR

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am looking for powershell script to create local account users in b2c along with authentication method as email for SSPR. Could some one please advise?

Answer (score 0):

That is not how AAD B2C works (although AAD does). In AAD B2C, the User Flow, or User Journey (Custom Policy), dictate what and how the user will reset the password. The default payload to create a B2C user is sufficient for a user to be compatible with a journey that forces the user to validate their email for password reset.

This is because such a journey simply reads their sign in email address and enforces they verify it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case , sign in name is user name not the mail .So I need to manually enter authentication method (as email) for the user from the portal otherwise SSPR is not working . Any other alternatives to make this work ?